# How can I set default value to a form field and then hide it away?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None # remove username field
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField('supervisor status', default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # fields required when creating a new user in terminal

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

forms.py

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm): 

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ("email",)

class StudentRegisterForm(MyUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']
```

So I want to create a student user based on my MyUser model. Everything should align with the fields on the MyUser model, the only difference here is that I want to set the "is_student" field to "True" automatically and hide this field away when I create a student user. How can I do that?

Comment: What about if the `is_student` field is **never** shown?- we just assume if it's being submitted with the `StudentRegisterForm` it's a student

Comment: Well, that's the idea of this post. Basically I set "is_student = False" for every newly created user, but when i create a student i wanna implicitly set it to "True" without having it display the tick box, but im just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You would override the default `.save()` method :)

```py
class StudentRegisterForm(MyUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super().save(commit=False)
        obj.is_student = True
        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj
```

I just wasn't sure if you wanted to see the field auto-checked yes on the new form, which would be a little more complex; especially when you look into showing but disabling the field, which is dumb.